# Infinite dimensional trace vs finite dimensional trace

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

For a Hilbert space $H$, and a linear operator $T:H\to H$, I've seen the trace of $T$ defined as $\sum_k<Te_k,e_k>$ (where $\{e_k\}$ is any orthonormal basis) provided this is finite.

How does this generalize the finite dimensional case? I see how this would generalize for self-adjoint operators (or normal on complex hilbert spaces) since these operators are unitarily diagonalizable. But what about a general linear operator on a finite dimensional space?

Comment: Can you give the definition of the trace of a general linear operator on a finite dimensional space you want to use?

Comment: You might be interested in the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator Also I think your question is how to generalize it to the infinite-dimensional setting, it says finite for the moment.

Comment: No need for diagonalisability. Consider the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\langle e_1, e_2, \dotsc, e_{\dim H}\rangle$.

Comment: @Bemte sum of complex eigenvalues

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, ok I understand. Thank you.